# I'm trying to insert aggregate function into a query but I keep get duplicated data

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate, aggregate-functions, where-clause

This is the query in which I'm talking data from:

```
SELECT client, make, model, units, expires AS [last checked], DateAdd("d",168,[expires]) AS [dates due]
FROM [servicing details]
WHERE expires >= DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,29) and expires <= DateSerial(Year(Date()),2,25);
```

[image of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH8dT.png)

This is the query of my aggregate functions:

```
 SELECT SUM(units) AS [total number of units], [dates due]
FROM [4th - 8th weeks]
GROUP BY [dates due];
```

[image of aggregate function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvxS4.png)

This is the query that I'm trying to combine them to show the total number of units but I'm getting duplicated data:

```
 SELECT clients.clients, [total number of units], [4th - 8th weeks].[dates due] 
 FROM clients,[4th - 8th weeks], [4th-8th units]
 WHERE clients.clients = [4th - 8th weeks].client
```

[image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoZrz.png)

I cant show u the clients data for privacy reasons but all 4 of them are the same in that query how to do i make it so its there are no duplicates

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: i have added images of the data and explain it a bit more does this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extended filter, I guess:

```sql
SELECT 
    clients.clients, [total number of units], [4th - 8th weeks].[dates due] 
FROM 
    clients,[4th - 8th weeks], [4th-8th units]
WHERE 
    clients.clients = [4th - 8th weeks].client
    AND 
    [4th - 8th weeks].[dates due] = [4th-8th units].[dates due]
```

But you should rebuild the query using *Inner Join* twice. Use the GUI query designer:

[Create a simple select query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-simple-select-query-DE8B1C8D-14E9-4B25-8E22-70888D54DE59)

Comment: thanks how would i rebuild it with using 2 inner joins

Comment: Use the GUI designer. Add the table and the queries, set the joins.

Comment: thanks couldn't quite get the gui designer to work properly though thats probably done to the fact that i have never used it before, though i did manage to mostly fix it by messing around with the sql

Comment: You must learn that. Added link to the answer. Read from start to finish.

Comment: Thanks that's a lot of help.